# Is it possible to see history procedure calls(with params) from packages?

Tags: oracle, logging, procedure

Unfortunately, colleagues did their procedure and did not make triggers and logs. Now I need to see the history of calls with params. I did not find anything in the system table v_$sql
Is it possible to view the history of procedure calls (with params) in system tables?

Answer (score 0):

Since it's no longer in V$SQL, it was likely more than a couple days ago. But it may be available. Sit down with your colleague and ask which SQL editor they use. Many use SQL Developer or TOAD for Oracle. Do these in order:

1. Have them connect to the schema and hit F8. An "SQL History" window will pop up that will show the history of SQL that was executed with "Run SQL" or F9. It doesn't store SQL executed using "Run as Script" or F5. TOAD for Oracle also has SQL history.
2. If that doesn't work, have them navigate to:
   C:\Users<user>\AppData\Roaming\SQL Developer\system<nn.n.n.nnn.nnnn>.history.

You'll find subdirectories in it with just numbers for names, 1 through 100 or more. **These are XML files that have SQL not found in SQL History.**

Just search the ".history" directory or look in the individual files by date. They have no extension but are text, so you can open them in a text editor.

3. If that fails, run a search of the whole drive with a search app that's better than Windows Search, like Agent Ransack or another. Search for a part of the procedure name, or even some of the code procedure code itself.

Hope this helps. Good luck.